# Derivative of a definite integral using properties

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

I know that $$ \frac{d}{dx} \int_a^{x}f(t)dt = f(x) $$ But I cannot find how to use this in order to calculate the derivative of this integral w.r.t $τ$:

$$ y(τ)=\frac{d}{dτ}\int_{τ-1}^{τ+1}\cos\left(\frac{πt}{8}\right)x(t)dt $$

Comment: The denominator of the LHS of the thing you've written should be $x$, not $t$.

Comment: Your notations are very misleading. You use the same $dt$ inside the integral and as the differentiation symbol in the denominator. Can you revise that in order for us to understand better?

Comment: Hint: write $\int_{\tau - 1}^{\tau+1} = \int_0^{\tau+1} - \int_0^{\tau-1}$.

Comment: Read up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$I = \int_{f(x)}^{g(x)}h(t) dt = H(g(x))-H(f(x))$$
Where $H(x)$ is the antiderivative of $h(x)$
$$\frac{dI}{dx} =  \frac{d}{dx}\int_{f(x)}^{g(x)}h(t) dt = \frac{d}{dx} H(g(x))-H(f(x))$$
$$\frac{d}{dx} H(g(x))-H(f(x)) = g'(x)H'(g(x)) - f'(x)H'(f(x))$$
Since $H'(x) = h(x)$
$$g'(x)H'(g(x)) - f'(x)H'(f(x)) =g'(x)h(g(x)) - f'(x)h(f(x))$$

For you,

$$I = \int_{r-1}^{r+1}\cos(\pi t/8)x(t) dt$$
$$\frac{dI}{dr} = \cos(\pi (r+1)/8)x(r+1) - \cos(\pi (r-1)/8)x(r-1)$$

Answer (score 0):

In general, you have

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}{f(x,t)dt}=f(x,h(x))\,h^{\prime}(x)-f(x,g(x))\,g^{\prime}(x)+\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,t)dt}$$